# Как не закрыть предыдущюю форму после закрытия новой java

Tags: java

Суть алгоритма такова : при нажатии на кнопку заполнить форму  открывается новая форма для заполнения предыдущей, т.е окон становится 2. Как только я заполнил форму на второй и хочу ее закрыть и перейти к предыдущей путем нажатия на 
       "Return to form", оно открывает новое окно с уже введенными данными , но проблема в том, что и предыдущее остается открытым, т.е получается две первые формы , которые заполнены от второй и это плохо. Нужно при нажатии на return to form закрывать предыдущее окно, но именно при нажатии. То есть не при нажатии на кнопку заполнить форму при переходе на  form2.java с  form1.java  а именно при переходе с form2.java  чтобы предыдущее form1.java  закрылось и открылось новое form1.java.  Как это реализовать не имею идей. Виндовлистенер не помог.

Есть form1.java

```
package zapol;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class form1
extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JButton btn1=new JButton("Open the form");
static JTextField txt1=new JTextField(3);
 static JTextField txt2=new JTextField(10);
JScrollPane scr=new JScrollPane(txt2);
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    form1 formw=new form1();

}
form1()
{
    setVisible(true);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setSize(200,150);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(btn1);
    btn1.addActionListener(this);
    add(txt1);
    add(txt2);      scr.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 110));
    add(scr, BorderLayout.CENTER);


}public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource()==btn1)
    {
        form2 formt=new form2();
    }
}
}
```

И form2.java

```
package zapol;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class form2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JButton btn1=new JButton("Return to form");
    JTextField txt1=new JTextField(10);
    JButton btn2=new JButton("Feel form");

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        form2 formw=new form2();

    }
    form2()
    {
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(200,150);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(btn1);
        btn1.addActionListener(this);
        add(btn2);
        btn2.addActionListener(this);
        add(txt1);

    }public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==btn1)
        {
            form1 formw=new form1();
            dispose();
        }
        if(e.getSource()==btn2)
        {String anys=form1.txt2.getText();
            form1.txt2.setText(form1.txt2.getText()+txt1.getText()+" , ");
            txt1.setText("");
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно не подсказывать . Сам понял как : нужно в форме 2

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==btn1)
        {
            form1 formw=new form1();
            dispose();
        }
```

исравить на

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==btn1)
        {
            dispose();
        }
```

. Во я слоупок